# Excel: Make a dynamic sum formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a dynamic sum formula in excel, which I have indicated in the screenshot (1). As you can see, the rows are the same except for H2, H3, H4, and H5. Instead of repeatedly adding more and more rows, I would like to have a cell that references how many of them should be there.

I understand that this is essentially a sum with i-->n, and a for loop would be fitting here, but I am curious if this could be achieved without VBA. Any ideas?

[image: Formula example]

[image: The example of data structure]

Comment: It would be useful if you could share an example of your data structure because right now this is not clear.

Comment: @karl added an example in the edit. Basically I'm trying to find the lowest sum of the consecutive numbers in this row, but I'd like to choose the amount of days. In this particular example I'm counting 4 days, since there are four lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this without relying on a VBA solution would be to use the `BYCOL()` function (available for Excel for Microsoft 365):

```
=BYCOL(array, [function])
```

The array specifies the range to which you want to apply your function, and the function itself is specified in a lambda statement. In the end, you want to get the minimum value of the sum of x consecutive days. Assuming that your data is stored in the range `E2:AI2` and the number of consecutive days is stored in cell `A1`, the function looks like this:

```
=MIN(BYCOL(E2:AI2,LAMBDA(col,SUM(OFFSET(col,,,,A1)))))
```

The `MIN()` part ensures that you get only the smallest sum of the array (all sums of the x consecutive values) returned. The array is simply the range in which your data is stored; it is named in the lambda argument `col` and consequently used by its name. In your case, you want to apply the sum function for, e.g., `x = 4` consecutive days (where 4 is stored in cell `A1`).

However, with this simple specification, you run into the problem of offsetting beyond cells with values toward the right end of the data. This means that the last sum you get would be 81.8 (value on 31 Jan) + 3 times 0 because the cells are empty. To avoid this, you can combine your function with an `IF()` statement that replaces the result with an empty cell if the number of empty cells is greater than 0. The adjusted formula looks like this:

```
=MIN(BYCOL(E2:AI2,
LAMBDA(col,IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(col,,,,A1),"")>0,"",SUM(OFFSET(col,,,,A1))))))
```

---

If you do not have the Microsoft 365 version, there are two approaches that would also work. However, the two approaches are a bit more tedious, especially for cases with multiple days (because the number of days can not really be set automatically; except for potentially constructing the ranges with a combination of `ADDRESS()` and `INDIRECT()`), but I would still argue a bit neater than your current specification:

```
=MIN(INDEX(E2:AF2+F2:AG2+G2:AH2+H2:AI2,0))

=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(E2:AF2+F2:AG2+G2:AH2+H2:AI2))
```

The idea regarding the ranges is the same in both scenarios, with a shift in the start and end of the range by 1 for each additional day.

Comment: I have to say @karl, your solution is absolutely brilliant. Didn't think that was possible without for loops! Thank you!